# Converting hOCR formatted text to Json

Tags: json, tesseract, hocr

Trying to implement a java class to convert hOCR output from Tesseract to JSON formatted data instead.
At the moment we use Abbey for our OCR service and they return JSON formatted data for the Words  location on the OCR'd image.  But Tesseract only returns hOCR.  So need to convert tesseracts output to match that of Abbey.

Comment: Do you know any specification of this json format from ABBYY? (We started to collect some similar transformations between OCR formats in https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/ocr-fileformat .)